# Can one define functions which operate on input data

Tags: function, input, gnuplot

I wonder if there is some workaround in Gnuplot to exchange something like

```
plot  input.dat using ($1/2):($2*2) axis x1y1 w lp
```

with

```
plot  input.dat using func1($1,$2):func2($1,$2) axis x1y1 w lp
```

with

```
func1(x,y) = x/2; func2(x,y) = y*2;
```

?

I would like to post-process my input data (line) before plotting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, using syntax very close to what you've suggested. Define the functions like this:

```
func1(x) = x / 2
func2(x) = x * 2
```

And use them like this:

```
 plot "input.dat" using (func1($1)):(func2($2))
```

That knot of parentheses in the plot statement is necessary.

You can define functions of more than one variable:

```
func3(x, y) = x * y
```

These are used similarly:

```
plot "input.dat" using (func1($1)):(func3($1, $2))
```

Comment: apparently, there is a limitation on number of parameters, so I can't do P2S22(g11,g12,g13,g21,g22,g23,g31,g32,g33,p11,p12,p13,p21,p22,p23,p31,p32,p33)...

Comment: @Denis Apparently, functions are limited to at most five variables, according to the [documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node60.html). But do you really need a function of 18 variables?

Comment: yes, I do, it's something that takes 2 matrixes (3x3) and output wariable, so I ended up just copy-pasting something like: ((($7*$16+$6*$15+($5+1.0)*$14)/(($5+1.0)*(($13+1.0)*($9+1.0)-$10*$12)+$7*($12*$8-$11*($9+1.0))-$6*(($13+1.0)*$8-$10*$11)))*br)

Comment: @Denis You might want to post that as an additional question, then - it's too much to try to work out in comments.

Comment: @Denis gnuplot is not designed to do extensive further calculations of your data. If you want to perform some matrix operations you should do them in a separate tool like [octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), write out the results and then plot those results using gnuplot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use functions in gnuplot. It is documented [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-6000013.4).

As an example:
With the data file *Data.csv*:

```
0.65734 0.59331
0.60033 0.76434
0.66493 0.43881
0.42811 0.42567
0.01783 0.57760
```

you can plot the data using functions like this:

```
func1(x) = x/2
func2(x,y) = y*2

plot "Data.csv" u (func1($1)):(func2($1, $2)) w l
```

Note the "extra" parentheses around `func1($1)` and `func2($1, $2)`. These tell gnuplot to evaluate the expression within them.